# Filter DataTable in c#

Tags: c#

I have a datatable like:

```
    ID | ID2
    --------
    1  |  2
    1  |  3
    12 |  2 
    15 |  3
```

I need to filter data table with ID2(I know two ID2 values in this case 2 and 3) in such a way that  i should get output as

```
    ID | ID2
    --------
    1  |  2
    1  |  3
```

That means ID which have two ID2(2 and 3) should be selected.

dt.Select("ID2=2 AND ID2=3");  is not working in this case.

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to tell what your intent is.  If you want all rows with ID2==3 && ID2==2 then nothing will match because ID2 can only hold a single value.  On the other hand, ID2==3 || ID2==2 matches all rows of your sample table.  Do you want a filter on ID==1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what are you searching for.
If you want to extract all the rows in which the same value for the ID column appears two or more times then

<strike>DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("Count(ID) > 1)")</strike>

You were right, this doesn't work on a datatable without relationships.
I have found a solution usig Linq,

```
// Returns an IGrouping<int,DataRow> for every ID that appears more than one time
var result = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(z => z.Field<int>("ID"))
             .Select(q=> new{Count = q.Count(), ID=q.Key})
             .Where(x => x.Count > 1);

// Now we could extract the rows in the usual way
foreach(var l in result)
{
    DataRow[] r = dt.Select("ID=" + l.ID);
    r.Dump();
}
```

I don't know how efficient is this, but at least this seems to work

Comment: + Good catch. This seems to be what OP is looking for.

Comment: This is not working..I am still getting all the rows instead of common rows for 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to DataSet

```
var rows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("ID") == 1);
```

BTW according to desired result you should filter by `ID`.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque but sample result is filtered by ID

Comment: The fact that all result rows have the same ID doesn't indicate that the rows are *filtered* by ID... in this case it's a consequence of some other filtering.